# Importing tokens from npm in Tailwind CSS config

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I'm checking out the Theme Configuration in Tailwind CSS. It looks really powerful, but I'm having trouble using my design tokens within the config.

I have my tokens distributed via npm, but don't know how I can include them in my `tailwind.config.js`. Is there any way to include them like this? Should I use a different approach?

```
// What I'm trying to achieve
import DesignTokens from "@my-design-system/tokens";

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      blue: DesignTokens.COLOR_BLUE_700,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Error I get

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Any info will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If your library supports commonjs then use `require` to grab the token. You're mixing module formats when you use `import` and `module.exports`. Your node runtime is expecting commonjs.

Comment: This is correct. Using `require` I was able to get it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, using the `import` is mixing module formats.

I got it working with the following configuration.

```
// I have tokens available in many different formats thanks to Style Dictionary. Here we use JSON.
const DesignTokens = require("@my-design-system/tokens.json");

module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      blue: {
        700: DesignTokens["color-blue-700"],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```